# Constructing a patch for either "git am" or "git apply"

Tags: git

I have been trying to apply a git patch that was not generated via git-format-patch(1) and which git has consequently failed to apply. The repository in question is publicly available here (https://github.com/acl2/acl2/) and the patch contents are publicly available here (https://utlists.utexas.edu/sympa/arc/acl2-help/2021-02/msg00016.html).

As you can see, the "patch" here is really the raw shell output of the git-diff(1) command. I started by downloading the email as a .eml file and attempting "git am" and "git apply". Both failed. I tried a few tweaks, including removing text past the end of the diff and pasting the diff contents into a different patch file that I know git to accept (and changing the diffstat just before the start of the diff to mention the correct files.) None of these tweaks worked either with the above two commands.

I'm aware this diff is small enough for it to take less time for me to apply it by hand than write to Stack Overflow, but something tells me this problem must have bothered someone else before and a solution must exist that actually uses git's patch application tools. Let me know - thanks!

Comment: `git apply` can read patches generated by `patch`. They will lack an `index` line for each blob, though, which means Git cannot locate a third version of a file if the patch's context does not match the *current* commit, as often happens with patches. With the index line providing a blob hash ID, Git *can* find the third version, and use that to perform a file-level merge operation.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've tried to do anything like this, so I have forgotten what transforms, if any, were appropriate. You probably would want or need `-p0` since Git diffs have the `a/` and `b/` prefixes on them, while plain patches usually don't have any prefix. It's also worth noting that using `patch` (the standalone utility) instead of `git apply` might be wiser anyway.

Comment: Here's what I see when I attempt to apply my edited patch, does it match what you expect?
--
128 git am 0001-Update-filesystem-books.patch
Applying: Update filesystem books
error: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 1 leading pathname component (line 12)
Patch failed at 0001 Update filesystem books
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch=diff' to see the failed patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
--

Comment: For what it's worth, "patch -p0" didn't work either. My error message looks like this:
--
can't find file to patch at input line 6
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/books/kestrel/std/system/ruler-extenders-plus-tests.lisp
|b/books/kestrel/std/system/ruler-extenders-plus-tests.lisp
|index 008e6304f..9a8f17604 100644
|--- a/books/kestrel/std/system/ruler-extenders-plus-tests.lisp
|+++ b/books/kestrel/std/system/ruler-extenders-plus-tests.lisp
--------------------------
--

Comment: Ah, this diff does have a/ and b/ so `-p1` would probably be correct. But I see an `index` line too: are you sure this is a plain diff in the first place? (Or is that after you edited the diff? If so, I'd try `-p0` against the original un-edited diff.)

Comment: So when you looked at the message, you could see just before the start of the diff that the command which generated it was "git diff". Do you think that diff is usable without any changes with "patch -p1"? Let me try it and report back, regardless...

Comment: Hey, it worked! Thanks @torek. If you would like to move your suggestions in the comment section to an answer, I would be happy to accept.

Comment: I'm not quite sure which comments were the helpful ones. :-) Aha, looking back at the original question, I see you did say they were from `git diff`. I was thinking all along that they were from plain `diff` (Unix diff), or some command that generates similar context diffs.